# How can I calculate the reflectivity of an electron gas with Thomson scattering?

Tags: electrons, scattering, laser, scattering-cross-section, particle-accelerators

I have to do a seminar presentation about the topic of using relativistic mirrors in integrated laser ion accelerator systems.

The idea is (for context sake) to accelerate an electron bunch to relativistic speeds and then shoot a laser pulse on the electrons. So the frequency, pulse length and amplitude of the pulse changes because of relativistic doppler effect.

The question now is how can I calculate the reflectivity of the electron bunch?

*Im following a paper that will be linked bellow (the paper and the doctor thesis)

The idea is to use Thomson scattering and therefore the Thomson cross section
$$
\sigma_T=6.65 \times 10^{-25} \mathrm{~cm}^2
$$

this is the cross section (as I understood) for the interaction of a photon and an electron.

We can than write the backscattered power as:

$$
P_T=\frac{\sigma_T}{A}\left|\sum_{j=1}^N e^{i \mathbf{q} \cdot \mathbf{r}_{\mathbf{j}}}\right|^2 P_i
$$

(what I do not fully understand. I guess $\left|\sum_{j=1}^N e^{i \mathbf{q} \cdot \mathbf{r}_{\mathbf{j}}}\right|^2$ represents somehow the superposition of the backscattered electromagnetic waves, and $e^{i \mathbf{q} \cdot \mathbf{r}_{\mathbf{j}}}$ is probably the wave functions of the backscattered light, but why is it squared?)

$A$ is the cross section of the electron bunch, $\boldsymbol q$ is the momentum transfer or scattering vector (which I also have a bit of a problem grasping) $\boldsymbol r_j$ is the distance vector between to electrons (such that the phase is given by $\phi = \boldsymbol q\cdot\boldsymbol r$) and $P_i$ is the incident power given by $P_i = A \cdot I_i$ (where $I_i$ is the incident intensity).

We than can write $P_T$ as:

$$
P_T=\frac{\sigma_T}{A}\left[N[1-f(\mathbf{q})]+N^2 f(\mathbf{q})\right] P_i
$$

(I also don't get why this should be the case)
where the form factor
$$
f(\mathbf{q})=\left|\int e^{i \mathbf{q} \cdot \mathbf{r}} S(\mathbf{r}) d^3 r\right|^2
$$
is given by the square amplitude of the Fourier transform of the normalized particle distribution function $S(\boldsymbol r)$.

From there on we proceed in deriving a reflectivity factor. I think I should be able to understand the rest of the Analytical Model by understanding this parts.

Thank you in advance for the response(s).

Best,
Lucas

Links:
(paper) https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms2775
(doctor thesis) https://edoc.ub.uni-muenchen.de/15379/